# Loaded Kernel Driver Version on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, kernel, driver

I can't seem to find a way to find the version of a loaded filter driver in windows by cmd\powershell\python

Driverquery and WMI-Win32_systemDriver finds the driver without the version number.

DriverView by NirSoft is doing a good job but i need to do this by code (without using a third-party app).

Suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

It may be that metadata and version number among them is not saved in loaded drivers on the memory (not file system)

This may change the question - how to check if a loaded driver (on the memory) is different from the driver file on the file system ?

Comment: Sure that driver loaded and driver from systemroot are same. Is not possible that two files have same name in directory.

Comment: It is possible, *.sys files (from drivers directory) can be deleted or replaced even if the driver is loaded in the memory. UPDATE: @user2120666 just making sure the comparison is between a file on the disk to a binary that's on the memory (not on a disk)

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that no possible delete driver, while running.

Comment: I tried it with asr mobility agent and it worked. i think the file of the driver is loaded right after reboot and once it's loaded the file is not needed or needed occasionally.